# Is there a linear transformation $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}$ such that $T(1, 2)=3$, $T(2, 2)=-1$ and $T(2, 5)=\frac{19}{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Will there exist a $TL$, $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(1, 2)=3$, $T(2, 2)=-1$ and $T(2, 5)=\frac{19}{2}$? Justify your answer.

According to me, if there exists such a linear transformation. Because if $T(2, 2)=-1$, then the linearity property of $T$ would imply that

\begin{align*}
-1&=T(2,\: 2)\\
&=T\left[ 6(1,\: 2)+\left(-2(2,\: 5)\right) \right] \\
&=6T(1,\: 2)-2T(2,\: 5) \\
&=6(3)-2\left( \frac{19}{2}\right) \\
&=18-19 \\
&=-1
\end{align*}

The same for the rest. Note that the vectors are linearly dependent, $6(1, 2)+(2, 2)+2(2, 5)=0$.

Comment: Use the first two to solve, and see if the third fits the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint:

If there is such linear transformation then there should be a solution to

$$\begin{align}
x+2y&=3\\
2x+2y&=-1\\
2x+5y&=\frac{19}{2}
\end{align}
$$

The transformation then it'd be $T(a, b) = ax+by$. If no solution to the system above exists, then there is no such $T$.

Comment: I obtain as solution $x=-4$ and $y=\frac{7}{2}$. Is it ok?

Comment: @Gabriela: Yes, $T(a, b)= -4a+7b/2$ seems to work.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.